# Porque al igualar 2 instancias una dependerá para siempre de la otra

Tags: java, punteros

Si tengo por ejemplo:

```
Class1 loc1 = new Class1(int1,int2);
Class1 loc2 = new Class1 (int3,int4);

loc1 = loc2
```

En este caso, si `loc2` cambia sus valores en adelante, `loc1` igualmente cambiará, pero en cambio si tengo:

```
double num1 = 10;
Class1 loc1 = new Class1(num1,num1);
Class1 loc2 = new Class1 (int3,int4);
num1 = 20;
```

Los atributos de `loc1` no cambian cuando se reasigna `num1=20`, porque sucede esto?

Comment: Cuando haces esto: `loc1 = loc2` lo que ocurre es que copias *referencias de objetos*, no los objetos en sí. A partir de ese momento lo que ocurrirá es que tanto `loc1` como `loc2` apuntarán al mismo objeto. En cuanto al segundo caso, nada ocurre porque el cambio de `num1` se hizo una vez creado el objeto. Si el valor debiera cambiar a `20` simplemente porque cambiaste la variable con que el objeto se creó inicialmente, la POO se vendría abajo, sería un desastre. Generalmente las clases encapsulan sus campos y sólo puedes cambiarlos mediante un método *setter*, por ejemplo: `loc1.setNum(20);`

Answer (score 4):

Al hacer `loc1=loc2` lo que ocurre es que copias *referencias de objetos*, no los objetos en sí. A partir de ese momento, tanto `loc1` como `loc2` apuntarán a este objeto:

```
Class1 loc1 = new Class1(int1,int2);
```

Eso lo puedes ver muy fácil con una simple prueba.

Supongamos una clase `Alumno` donde creamos dos instancias:

```
    Alumno alumnoOne = new Alumno(1,"Pedro");
    Alumno alumnoTwo = new Alumno(2,"Juan");
```

Luego hacemos algo parecido a lo tuyo:

```
    /*Aquí vamos a poner un breakpoint y depuraremos*/
    alumnoTwo=alumnoOne;
```

Si examinas las variables antes del *breakpoint*, o sea, antes de haber igualado `alumnoTwo` a `alumnoTwo`, verás esto en la descripción de variables (estoy usando NetBeans):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada referencia tiene sus datos propios.

Ahora bien, si sigues corriendo el código, dejando que continúe y ocurra: `alumnoTwo=alumnoOne;` verás lo siguiente en la descripción de variables:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes probarlo de otra forma muy sencilla:

```
System.out.println(alumnoOne==alumnoTwo);
    alumnoTwo=alumnoOne;
System.out.println(alumnoOne==alumnoTwo);
```

Verás que te imprimirá esto:

```
false
true
```

Ya sabrás por qué.

---

En cuanto al segundo caso, nada ocurre porque el cambio de `num1` se hizo una vez creado el objeto. Si el valor en la instancia del objeto creado debiera cambiar a `20` simplemente porque cambiaste la variable con que la instancia del objeto se creó inicialmente, la POO se vendría abajo, sería un desastre.

Generalmente las clases encapsulan o mejor dicho, la programación orientada a objetos exige que sus campos sean encapsulados, para poder cambiarlos solamente mediante determinados métodos conocidos como *setter*.

En tu caso, para cambiar el número, la clase debería estar dotada de un método parecido a este:

```
public void setNum (int num)
{
    this.num=num;
}
```

Este método sería el único que tendría potestad para cambiar el atributo `num` de tu clase, haciendo algo como: `loc1.setNum(20);`

Answer (score 1):

En el primer caso, `loc1` y `loc2` son dos objetos. Veo que se crea una zona de memoria para `loc1` y otra diferente para `loc2`. Sin embargo, con la línea `loc1` = `loc2`, se hace que `loc1` pase a apuntar (es decir a usar) a la zona de memoria de `loc2`. Por ello cambiando los valores de `loc2`, se ven cambios en los de `loc1`

En el segundo caso, la variable `num1` está apuntando a una zona de memoria, en la que se ha guardado el valor 10. 
A continuación, se hace `new` sobre `loc1` y se reserva un espacio de memoria nuevo usado exclusivamente por `loc1` (tal y como está el código).

A continuación, se cambia el valor de `num1` a 20, es decir, en la zona de memoria donde antes había un 10, ahora está el valor 20. Pero este cambio no afecta a la zona de memoria donde se guarda la información de `loc1`

Answer (score 1):

No dependen.

Son clases y por lo mismo son tipos **referencia**.

Esto quiere decir que cuando tienes una variable de una clase y la asignas no estás asignando el objeto como tal, sino una referencia al objeto. Es decir su dirección en memoria.

Así que si asignas la dirección de memoria del objeto en otra variable pues ambas están haciendo referencia al mismo objeto.

No sucede lo mismo con los tipos valor como las `struct`, los tipos nativos como `int`, `float`, `double` o los tipos inmutables como `string`.  Estos tipos  valor cada vez que los asignas lo que haces es crear copias de ellos mismos.

Y esa es la razón por la que te sucede esa situación.